# SQL Database Algorithm

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, data-modeling

I have a little big projects that should manage a projects for a goverment
I did thats already but it get complicated when they want to put all projects types in this one database and finaly get one detailed report for everything in database.
They have few projects type about 20 types, fields are different from type to other and every projects type table have many detail tables so if I want to make a table to every type I should also make that's many details tables so my database will have too many tables and it will be really hard to work with it.
I wonder what is the best algorithm to do that?
Should I put all in one master table? But if I did project id will be conflicted because every projects type start with id (1) so I will have problem with this and finaly if I did it like that will I be able to get what I want from database like reports, views and queries (from my application) as when its splitted into different tables?
Example:
Projets Types (Master Tables): 
Building Projects, Elctric Projects, Painting Projects, Repairing Projects, Direct Projects, etc.
Some tables contain field `Company` some other tables doesn't
Some tables contain field `Contract` some other tables doesn't 
and so on.
Details Tables for every table:
Durations, Costs, Workers, Rating, etc.
If I split Master tables as above I should split details too and that will give so many tables and make it really hard to work with database.
Maybe it's ot hard as I think but It's first time i work with big project like this so I'm not sure how to do it and there will be very important information if something happened and lost it, it will be very bad to my life.

Comment: Please define more details or some example. Currently it's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: @VadimLevkovsky Thanks for reply I added more details and information

Comment: What you're asking here is essentially "how do I do data warehousing." This is way too broad a topic for someone to answer here. I would strongly suggest that you read up on the basics of data warehousing and ETL, particularly focusing on how to deal with integrating related data from multiple sources. When you have specific questions about specific problems you face along the way, you can always come back and ask about those issues here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even though this question is Way too broad, and actually not asking anything, i'll give it a few minutes of attention.

1) You backup the current state and work on a Sandbox!

2) if your only need is few reports, i guess you can generate them query the different databases independently and maybe post processing the results.
e.g. Sum ProjectsData.Totalcost as TotalCost.
note: some data will be harder to derive.

3) think of Testcases against your expected data...
   then see if your Testcase reach the manually calculated entry

4) if you must Join them into One DB, then you are into a lot of trouble matching data.
  4.1) Yes, you should create a new table `Projects : project_id, title, ...`
  4.2) You should create Column `project_id` to almost every table in your merged DB
  4.3) You should write your migration code with as many Data Validations as you can! and make your output-log worthwhile.

4.4) when finally running on production, Keep your Original DBs, your Output-log & migration scripts for years to come!

Still, i think this question should address a more specific issue in migrating your multiple databases into one.